# R.prop flow type

Tags: flowtype, ramda.js

I have the following code:

`const myObject: { myProperty: number } = { myProperty: 2 };
const myProp = R.prop('myProperty', myObject);`

I expect the type of myProp to be number but i get ?number.

Since I assure flow that myObject has a property myProperty that is not null or undefined on line 1 shouldn't this be possible?

Im using ramda v0.24.1 and flow-bin v0.59.0

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I had an outdated version of ramda flow-typed definitions. 
myProp now becomes number as expected.